# Tracking DISM progress using C# - Working in Windows 10 but not in WinPE

Tags: c#, winpe, dism

I am using C# to start DISM process to capture/apply image and to track the progress.

When I run the code on Windows 10 the progress is being updated normally but when the code I run the code inside WinPE environment the progress is not updated but the process is still running normally.

This is the code that triggers the method to start DISM.
Just to note it is running on .NET Framework 4.0

```
Task T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                ApplyImage(machineName, imageIndex, imageDescription);
                                //Utilities.BailOut();
                            });
```

This is the code that I am using to start DISM, Arguments change depending on the needs.

```
     public void ApplyImage(string imageName, int imageIndex)
            {
                string _imageName = imageName;
                int _index = imageIndex;
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    FileName = "Dism.exe",
                    Arguments = $@"/apply-image /imagefile:{OS_Deploy}\{_imageName} /index:{_index} /applydir:{TargetDisk}"
                };
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => setLabelText(lblProgress, e.Data);
                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();
                process.CancelOutputRead();
                process.Close();
            }
```

And this is the code that is setting the label text

```
private void setLabelText(Label label, string text)
        {
            if (label.InvokeRequired)
            {
                label.Invoke((System.Action)(() => setLabelText(label, text)));
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (text.Contains("%"))
                    {
                        label.Text = "Status : " + text.Split('%')[0].Substring(text.Split('%')[0].Length - 4, 4) + "%";
                    }
                    else if (text == "The operation completed successfully.")
                    {
                        label.Text = "Completed!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label.Text = text;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
```

What could be causing this issue and what can I to fix it or maybe create a workaround?